# Modifying video frames with QTKit and OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, qtkit

I am working on a project where I would like to open a video (on a Mac) with QTKit.  That part I can do no problem, but as I am playing it, I would like to edit or modify the video on the fly using OpenGL.

From what I understand, I should be able to intercept the frames and change them before it hits the display, but no matter what I do, I cannot seem to do so.

Comment: Soooo....what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I found this posting.  http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/10/core-animation-tutorial-rendering-quicktime-movies-in-a-caopengllayer/  This project works, but if I modify it to select a video rather than use a video in the sample, all it does is play, it does not call only of the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should have a look at [Core Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Concepts/CVProg_Concepts.html) and the display link mechanic.
You can basically get a callback on a high priority thread with the decoded frame in a CVImageBuffer and do whatever you like with it (including packing it up as a texture for OpenGL processing and display).
Apple provides documentation and [demo code snippets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Tasks/CVProg_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001536-CH203-DontLinkElementID_13) on the developer sites.